# rsync timeout when copying folders of mounted volume to local folder

Tags: shell, applescript, rsync, mount

Everytime I start the applescript (with a shell-command), it should **transfer not existing folders and files (recursively) into the localfolder** *(after connecting to a VPN and mounting the volume – both works nice)*.

```
mount volume "smb://dfdfdf.ch/e_18_data11$"
delay 4

set sourcefolder to quoted form of POSIX path of ("/Volumes/e_18_data11$/folder1/folder2")
set localfolder to quoted form of POSIX path of ("/Users/dfdfdf/Dropbox/test")

try
    do shell script "/usr/bin/rsync -arvuE --delete " & sourcefolder & " " & localfolder
end try
```

this gives me a **rsync timeout** (first error described below):

```
--> error "rsync: read errors mapping \"/Volumes/e_18_data11$/folder1/folder2/test.pdf\":     Operation timed out (60)
```

so, basically, it **starts syncing**, then it **disconnects first the volume** (like below) and then it **disconnects the VPN**, too. Why? What should I improve? 
Thank you.

**edit:**
The source folder size: ~ 1GB

[image: volume disconnect]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to **rsync version 3** (instead of OS X Standard Version 2.6) solved the problem.